# How to hide a panel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

!I am using Wpf. I want to show two panels if one is visible other should hide. Both should be at same margin. Image below will explain my question in detail.

[image]

Thanks,
Annie

Can any one will guide me that how to code this?

Comment: Is it a request or question? What's the problem? What have you tried? What failed?

Comment: try to toggle b/w Visibility of panels....

Comment: what you try? paste some code

Comment: PanelB.Visibility=Visiblity.Collapsed;

Comment: Annie, please get to know the class hierarchy of the WPF controls. A Panel is UIElement and as such inherits the Visiblity property (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx).

Comment: Annie, what have you tried? This is really simple in WPF, but we need to know if you tried something or if you're looking for a deeper explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't have VS, so it should be something like this

```
  <Button x:Name="ToggleButton" Click="ToggleButton_Click"></Button>



 private void ToggleButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Panel1.Visibility == System.Windows.Visibility.Visible)
            {
                Panel2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
                Panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                Panel2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
                Panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
```

Comment: The namespace should be `System.Windows`, shouldn't it?

Comment: oh my mistake, got struck into Windows 8 app store

Comment: `System.Windows.Visibility`, to be precise.

Comment: now it is okey i guess

Comment: It is result of working with WinRT  :p

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this...

```
        newButton.Click += (o, ev) =>
        { 
            panelA.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            panelB.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        }
        closeButton.Click += (o, ev) =>
        {
            panelB.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
            panelA.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is very simple:

```
Panel1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
Panel2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Comment: Is `Hidden` rather than `Collapsed` an appropriate choice here? The drawing in the question doesn't look like the space of the other panel should remain reserved.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Assuming you are using MVVM pattern)

Bind both stack panel's visibility with 2 public properties(bool). And on set property of both, check if its visibility==true then set visibility of other control to false.

Use following visibility converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    bool bValue = (bool)value;
    if (bValue)
        return Visibility.Visible;
    else
        return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

And on xaml you should bind this stack panel's visibility as

```
Visibility="{Binding Panel1Visibility,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"
```

Comment: [WPF's visibility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.visibility.aspx) is **not** a boolean.

Comment: Yes I know. You have to write converter for that. BooleanToVisbility Converter.

Comment: Exactly. Your answer should mention that instead of stating an impossible "set visibility of other control to false."

Comment: Use this

public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
     bool bValue = (bool)value;
     if (bValue)
         return Visibility.Visible;
     else
         return Visibility.Collapsed;
}

Comment: I think answer is fine now. Is it.?

Comment: The answer hasn't changed at all and thus StackOverflow won't let me undownvote yet. Can you add the converter source code to your answer? Even then (though I would undownvote then), note that I somehow have a hunch the OP will need more of an explanation about how, where and why to actually use the converter for this answer to become really helpful (and thus accepted).

Comment: Converter is good when you bind with ViewModel, and your view model has Y/N or T/F...there you need converter

Answer (score 0):

Use this vibility converter

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
   bool bValue = (bool)value;
   if (bValue)
     return Visibility.Visible;
   else
     return Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Simply put panel1.hide() and panel2.show

Comment: [The WPF `Panel` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.aspx) does not have any `hide` or `show` method.